# Convert String Datatype column to "Embeddedlist" datatype in Orientdb

Tags: orientdb

I have a column "userUnits" as string data-type with respect to user and userUnits column having multiple units entered separated by the comma(,) as user1 userUnits are **"admin,manager"** and user2  userUnits are "admin" as string datatype and I have to convert it into "embeddedlist" data-type as user1 userUnits will be **["admin","manager"]** and user2 userUnits will be ["admin"]
so how can I convert it for all the users?
can anyone help me with this please

Comment: Hi, Could you accept a javascript function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem

[image]

I used this query

```
update user set newProperty=userUnits.asList()
```

and I got

[image]

To remove the property userUnits from your records, you could use

```
update user remove userUnits
```

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

You can use this javascript function

```
var g=orient.getGraphNoTx();
g.command("sql","CREATE PROPERTY User.newProperty embeddedlist" );
var users = g.command("sql","select from User");
for(i=0;i<users.length;i++){
    var record=users[i];
    var id=record.getId();
    var userUnits=record.getProperty("userUnits");
    var array=userUnits.split(",");
    var myvalue='"';
    for(j=0;j<array.length;j++){
        if(j==0)
            myvalue+=array[j]+'"';
        else
            myvalue+=',"'+array[j]+'"';
    }
    g.command("sql","UPDATE " + id + " set newProperty = [ " + myvalue + "]");
}
g.command("sql","UPDATE user REMOVE " + userUnits);
```

Comment: thanks for your help
the results are getting same as you displayed BUT we need to convert the data with comma separated as ["admin","manager"]
but till now we are getting ["admin,manager"]
here  **["admin,manager"]** is a **single** userUnit but it should be **two** with comma separated as **["admin","manager"]**